# Permission Sets and Custom Settings

Tags: security

I would like to take the advantage of permission sets in my org but I don't find the way to include custom settings on permission sets.

Any suggestion?

Thanks
Agustina

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Pete, it seems I was wrong. Latest response from Salesforce is that they are not included on Permission Sets, and as custom setting can be at org level, then they should not be supported by permission sets. But they delivered by Winter '15 Custom Permissions that are supported by permission sets and they can help you to get functionality that maybe a custom setting provides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Custom settings* by default have a security model built into them.

They have an org/group/individual level when you setup the hierarchy, and default to the next level in the permission set if they have not yet been set for an individual or profile id.

Org > Profile > Individual.

See: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Calling methods like: `getInstance` will return appropriate settings for the user depending on what has been created.

Comment: I think you mean to refer to Custom Settings in your first sentence, not Permission Sets.

Comment: whoops fixed...

Answer (score 2):

we've discussed internally whether to add permission sets to custom settings. The jury is still out whether it would make sense.

Can you tell me more about the use case?

Comment: Adam,thanks for your comment. When I started with this new project, I used profiles as start point, so my idea was to move those elements I could find there to our new permission sets. That's the only reason why we wanted to include them, because some of our <objectPermissions> are our custom settings. But this is not a must for us, we can leave them on Profile for now. Thanks

Comment: We have this exact problem.  We want to give access to a specific set of users to manage the data in a custom setting through a Visualforce page.  We've been able to grant the users delegated administration access to the custom setting, but this means they can just edit the meta data and not manage the data itself.  We don't want to give the Customize Application permissions to the end users.  Adam - is there a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Adam, we have a use case where we're using a custom setting to configure which users have access to certain features in different orgs ("feature flags"). As we're rolling out new features we would like to give access to selected groups of "pilot" users. Right now we need to clone the profile they're in and re-assign a select group of users to the new profile to give them access. Being able to specify a hierarchical custom setting on the permission set level would allow us to selectively give access to these features across profiles.